# Filtering result

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

It is regarding filtering the result. Following code is working fine. But I would like to add one more field. video.description want to add along with video.title

```
      exports.getSearchvideo = async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const videos = await Video.find();
        const index = videos.filter(
          video =>
            video.title
              .toLowerCase()
              .toString()
              .indexOf(req.params.word.toLowerCase().toString()) > -1
// want to add video.description
        );
        res.send(index);
      } catch (error) {}
    };
```

Comment: Can you please show given input and expected output?

Comment: Input and output are array object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
const result = videos.filter(v => 
  ['title', 'description'].some(prop =>
    v[prop].toLowerCase().includes(req.params.word.toLowerCase()))
)
```

Code example:

```js
// API videos response
const videos = [{ title: 'Title for Video 1', description: 'Description', }, { title: 'Title for Video 2', description: 'Some description here' }]
const word = 'VIDEO 1'

const result = videos.filter(v =>
  ['title', 'description'].some(prop => v[prop].toLowerCase().includes(word.toLocaleLowerCase()))
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute more then just one line of code, you can use the curly brackets.

for example:

```
video => { 
    const titleResult = video.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(req.params.word.toLowerCase()) > -1 
    const descriptionResult = video.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(req.params.word.toLowerCase()) > -1 
    return result1 && result2 
}
```

And you don't need toString() after toLowerCase(), because it already returns string

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not need to add `toString` after `toLowerCase` - `toLowerCase` is a member function of `string`, so you'd get an error for calling it on a value that is not a string (if anything, if you're not sure of the input, do a `toSatring().toLowerCase()`).

Second, you can use `.includes` to find a substring. No need for `indexOf`.

Finally, if you need to add another condition, use the logical AND (`&&`) to add the `description` condition to the filter function:

```
const index = videos.filter(
    video =>
        video.title.toString().toLowerCase()
            .includes(req.params.word.toString().toLowerCase())
        && video.description.toString().toLowerCase()
            .includes(req.params.anotherWord.toString().toLowerCase())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `.filter` callback you can't modify a value.
Use `forEach` instead. So, you loop through the videos once and you can do with a value whatever you want.

```js
const videos = [ {a:1}, {b:2} ]
const result = []

videos.forEach(value => {
   if (value.a) {
      value.desription = 'test'
      result.push(value)
   }
})

result -> [ {a: 1, description: 'test'} ]
```